# Entity Framework : get all entities with specific type

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework to read/write data to the DB and wondering if there is a way to get the entities by type. For example: I have `Student` table and `Classroom` table (in reality, I have bunch of tables). I would like to get all the students by using the type or entity name. Basically I need something generic to read the data from the DB.

The solution I have is to use reflection to read the `DbContext` properties that returns `IQueryable`, but it seems there should be another way of doing it. If so, can someone tell me how to do it?

I need something like this:

`dbContext.GetEntities<T>()`

or

```
dbContext.GetEntities(Type entityType)
```

Comment: How do you want to specify the type? Maybe you should add some tentative code to clarify what you want.

Comment: I think its slightly unclear but should not be closed. It has got an appropriate answer by @marc_s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
DbSet<T> allEntities = yourDbContext.Set<T>();
```

where you can replace `T` with any of your entity types, e.g. with `Student`:

```
DbSet<Student> allStudents = yourDbContext.Set<Student>();
```

and if you need the `IQueryable`, just use `.AsQueryable()`:

```
IQueryable<Student> allStudents = yourDbContext.Set<Student>().AsQueryable();
```

Please study the [official MSDN documentation on `DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) for more details and more properties and method on that class